# Google Chrome doesn't launch anymore on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

As my title says, **Google Chrome** is not running when I try to launch it. In fact, nothing is happening. When I double click on it I see that the cursor changes to the *"loading cursor"* for a moment and then the system behaves as if I've never clicked or done anything.

I'm running under **Windows 10 Professional 64 bits** and I have **Kaspersky Internet Security** as antivirus.

I've tried to disable Kaspersky and the firewall but nothing has changed.
I also uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome but same problem.
I have even reinstalled Windows 10 and downloaded the latest update but I still have the same issue.

I searched a lot on the internet and I saw that many people had this problem. I tried everything that I found but absolutely nothing worked.

I also encounter the same behavior with Internet Explorer.

For information it used to work correctly.

**EDIT:**

After reading *CHMartinK* answer, I can say that **Kaspersky** is the problem.
When I exit it totally, I can open Chrome but as soon as I enable it, I can't acces to any website.

Comment: Break all partitions, make them again, reformat and reinstall Windows. If it still doesn't work, ditch Chrome.

Comment: I think that it's a drastic solution to maybe use in last resort. Especially as I read elsewhere that some people did already that but still remain with the same problem. And i can't ditch Chrome as I'm a web developer so it's not for a personal use but for my work.

Comment: Did Chrome ever work before on this specific machine?

Comment: Yes it used to work correctly as I mentioned it in my question.

Comment: Then when did it stop working? Driver update? Windows update? Chrome update? Any hardware change? Spontaneous?

Comment: To be honest I don't remember well but I suspect Kaspersky to be the cause of the problem (I also read it on other websites). I changed my machine few months ago and at the begining I was not using any antivirus. But Windows 10 plays surely a role because I have other machines with Kaspersky and I've never encountered any problem.

Comment: Do you have System Restore enabled? If yes, did you try restoring to an earlier date when Chrome was working, hope you have such a restore point created before. What happens when you run Chrome from command prompt?

Comment: I have a restoration point but I did it at the very beginning. I would lose lots of files and applications if I apply it. It's a real weird issue and I'm really confused and frustrated. To answer your last question, when I run Chrome from command line it does exactly the same, that is to say nothing

Comment: @user688496 - You should submit your own answer and in detail tells us what your ultimate solution was. instead of including the solution in the question body.

Comment: "When I exit it totally, I can open Chrome but as soon as I enable it, I can't acces to any website." - Kaspersky Internet Security has the capability to scan your secure http traffic, you should disable this feature, and any Kaspersky browser add-on and/or any feature that communicates with your browser.  This will allow you to have Kaspersky enabled and use Chrome at the sametime.

Answer (score -1):

Did you install the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Chrome?

Perhaps even more importantly, did you use the "personal" version of Chrome that installs within the user profile, or did you install the "enterprise" variety that helps ensure everyone on that local machine is using the same version?  I definitely tend to favor this one… it is more of a traditional application install.  Try downloading the 64-bit version and see if it works:

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/business/browser/admin/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I've already downloaded the 64 bit version and it changed nothing.

Comment: That is unfortunate.  Hopefully someone else will chime in with a better suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same Issue. Have an INC open with Kaspersky and we try to fix it... still no solution.
But, try to exit Kasypersky fully and then try to start chrome. The it should start. For me this is working.
Exit Kaspersky
Start Chrome
Start Kaspersky
and do not close chrome till the day ist over :-/
I wondering if it is also working for you.
Regards
Martin

Comment: This does not answer the author's question.

Comment: I don't know why you recieved a down vote but what you said worked. So the problem is definetly **Kaspersky**. On the other hand as soon as I reactivate the antivirus, I cannot acces to any website. So I'll take a look on this.

Comment: @CHMartinK - Your comment is the exact a reason voting is anonymous.  Please keep it civil in the future.